# Android on-screen keyboard hiding Python Kivy TextInputs

Tags: android, python, kivy

I am just beginning to learn how to develop in Kivy, but I have a problem with the keyboard on Android. When I have series of TextInputs running down to the bottom of the screen, I cannot see the fields hidden by the on-screen keyboard.

Here is the screen display with and without the keyboard:

[without keyboard](http://hpics.li/8e5fcbf)

[With keyboard](http://hpics.li/4d61266)

Normally, I'd expect to be able to scroll the screen to display the relevant text input and select it but I cannot find out how to do so... :(

How can I handle this?

Comment: your question is not clear at all. You need to read [ask] to know how to post a question here and allow us to answer you ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, but my mother tongue is French and I have a little trouble with English...

Comment: I think the question is quite clear

Comment: Yes this question is very clear. He wants the user to be able to access each field but the native android keyboard covers half the screen but doesn't allow the user to scroll down to what's covered. If you don't understand someones question you can ask for more info but don't be rude about it. It's not his fault that you don't understand.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `softinput_mode` [property of Window](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.window.html#kivy.core.window.WindowBase.softinput_mode) to choose what happens when the keyboard is opened, and optionally use the `keyboard_height` to know how big the keyboard is and move your textinputs appropriately.

However, this is only available in kivy master (version 1.9). There will be another stable release including it soon.

Comment: how do i add kivy master version 1.9 to buildozer.spec

Answer (score 2):

Use 'Window', not 'Windows', and place in main.py:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.softinput_mode = 'pan'
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the thing you are looking for should look exactly like in(e.g?) main.py:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.softinput_mode = 'below_target'
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I installed version 1.9.0.
But where and how to put the code 
`Window.softinput_mode`?
when I put in my main:

```
from kivy.core.windows import Windows
Windows.softinput_mode = 'pan'
```

it does not work...